# Sitecore compliance for Authoring Tool Accessibility Guidelines (ATAG)?

Tags: accessibility

I've had this question on Sitecore's ATAG compliance when working on an opportunity in my previous agency. Unfortunately i don't have access to the materials and the response was from Sitecore sales and for a much older version of Sitecore than the current (8.2 Update-2).

The question is specifically for compliance of Content Management environment (Content Editor, Experience Editor, Analytics Dashboards etc).

I thought it was worth asking here on our Sitecore StackExchange to help others if the question crops up on another opportunity.

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be yes, but it's not as straigh forward and depends on the needs. There are multiple sollutions that might fit the needs.

For start the Sitecore editing interfaces, especially the Content Editor, are completelyusable from the keyboard.

In the past, I’ve have used the MS Word integration as a way of letting people with disabilities edit content on the site. As Microsoft have a good suite of accessibility tools (in the operating system and the product) this should allow a degree of content editing for those with disabilities.

Obviously, you still have to point out that with a rich dynamic interface such as Sitecore, or any web CMS, accessibility is going to be hard but with the strong Sitecore API (which has access to all the application functions) it is very easy to adapt parts of Sitecore for someone with special interface requirements. I've seen super-simplified way of entering content for news / press releases with a highly accessible form that created a Sitecore item on submission.